# Stuck at Getting Survey Details from SurveyMonkey REST Connection in QlikSense

Tags: rest, connection, qlikview, qliksense, surveymonkey

I'm trying to connect to the Survey Monkey API via a hard coded connection set in a variable but the connection is giving me such error:

```
QVX_UNEXPECTED_END_OF_DATA: HTTP protocol error 400 (Bad Request):

{
 "error": 
     {
      "docs": "https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#error-codes", 
      "message": "Invalid URL parameters.", "id": "1003", "name": "Bad Request", 
      "http_status_code": 400
     }
}
```

Although, if i try the same but while getting surveys bulk, it works

`vID` is equal to a survey `id`

```
let vURL2 = 'https://api.surveymonkey.com/v3/surveys/$(vID)/details';

RestConnectorMasterTable_SurveryFullDetails:
SQL SELECT 
    "response_count",
    "page_count",
    "date_created",
    "folder_id",
    "nickname",
    "id" AS "id_u3",
    "question_count" AS "question_count_u0",
    "category",
    "preview",
    "is_owner",
    "language",
    "footer",
    "date_modified",
    "analyze_url",
    "summary_url",
    "href" AS "href_u1",
    "title" AS "title_u0",
    "collect_url",
    "edit_url",
    "__KEY_root",
    (SELECT 
        "done_button",
        "prev_button",
        "exit_button",
        "next_button",
        "__FK_buttons_text"
    FROM "buttons_text" FK "__FK_buttons_text"),
    (SELECT 
        "__FK_custom_variables"
    FROM "custom_variables" FK "__FK_custom_variables"),
    (SELECT 
        "href" AS "href_u0",
        "description" AS "description_u0",
        "title",
        "position" AS "position_u2",
        "id" AS "id_u2",
        "question_count",
        "__KEY_pages",
        "__FK_pages",
        (SELECT 
            "sorting",
            "family",
            "subtype",
            "visible" AS "visible_u1",
            "href",
            "position" AS "position_u1",
            "validation",
            "id" AS "id_u1",
            "forced_ranking",
            "required",
            "__KEY_questions",
            "__FK_questions",
            (SELECT 
                "text",
                "amount",
                "type",
                "__FK_required"
            FROM "required" FK "__FK_required"),
            (SELECT 
                "__KEY_answers",
                "__FK_answers",
                (SELECT 
                    "visible",
                    "text" AS "text_u0",
                    "position",
                    "id",
                    "__FK_rows"
                FROM "rows" FK "__FK_rows"),
                (SELECT 
                    "description",
                    "weight",
                    "visible" AS "visible_u0",
                    "id" AS "id_u0",
                    "is_na",
                    "text" AS "text_u1",
                    "position" AS "position_u0",
                    "__FK_choices"
                FROM "choices" FK "__FK_choices")
            FROM "answers" PK "__KEY_answers" FK "__FK_answers"),
            (SELECT 
                "heading",
                "__FK_headings"
            FROM "headings" FK "__FK_headings")
        FROM "questions" PK "__KEY_questions" FK "__FK_questions")
    FROM "pages" PK "__KEY_pages" FK "__FK_pages")
FROM JSON (wrap on) "root" PK "__KEY_root"
WITH CONNECTION(Url "$(vURL2)");
```

Comment: Hi have you checked my answer about authorization header?

Comment: Hi, has my answer helped?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [this fairly exhaustive SurveyMonkey how to guide](https://community.qlik.com/t5/Qlik-Sense-Enterprise-Documents/Using-the-Qlik-Sense-REST-Connector-with-SurveyMonkey/ta-p/1479259) on the Qlik Community? Might we worth checking you've followed all those steps, including giving the user permission to access the API.

Comment: Yes i used this guide to make my connections. But when i reached the loop part, while looping into the Survey details. It throws me this error. Do you have any idea about pagination and the use of next url in the "WITH CONNECTION"

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to hardcode URL, you also need to specify authorization header

```
WITH CONNECTION (
Url "$(vURL2)",
HTTPHEADER "Authorization" "bearer YOUR_TOKEN"
);
```